# Grouping multiple lines onto one in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, grouping

How can I get this data set in Image 1 to look like the data in Image 2. Basically rather than having each purchase on its own line I want to group by Name and have all that persons purchases on one line. They can buy a max of 5 items and my database is about 30 million lines worth of purchases.

P.S The date order is not important

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then item end) as item_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as date_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then item end) as item_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end) as date_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then item end) as item_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then date end) as date_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by date asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT` with `row_number` as follows:

```
Select * from 
   (select t.*,
           row_number() over (partition by name order by date_purchased) rn
      from your_table t
  ) PIVOT
(Max(item_purchased), max(date_purchased) For rn in (1,2,3));
```